# Sprite and animation making tool for android game

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

I am new at Android game development. I want to know how can i create and Animate the game characters i have in mind. Is there a tool out there that can help me get started with the drawing or i have to draw frame-by-frame.

I am targeting simple 2D games.

Comment: Sounds like you need a graphic designer.

Answer (score 7):

What you'll need is a sprite sheet.  A series of images on the same bitmap laid out in a grid.  For example you would have 8 different sprites of the same character, 1 standing still., 1 left foot forward, 1 right foot forward and jumping and again facing the opposite direction.

When you draw the sprite set the coordinates to be drawn and on button presses change the variables controlling the coordinates.

A good tutorial is here http://warriormill.com/2009/10/adroid-game-development-part-1-gameloop-sprites/

and a sprite sheet maker can be found here http://www.codeandweb.com/sprite-sheet-maker

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for the reply! and the links really helped... but i was wondering if i could get some help with how the art-work is really made .. i mean sure there are sprite sheets with the animation frames but how do we make those frames is there some system or set of rules?

Comment: sorry for not answering sooner! here is a great tutorial on making a sprite sheet
http://spritedatabase.net/tutorial_sheet.php